# Set background color for Alexa APL smart display devices

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

How to set a background color for an Amazon Alexa APL skill?
This is how my .json file looks like:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-sauce-boss/master/lambda/custom/documents/recipeIntent.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you have some background images that used `best-fill` and also a defined size `100vw`x`100vh` so I was wondering where would you like to add a background color.

The solution I found for a similar case was adding a Frame like this:

```
{
  "type": "Frame",
  "width": "100vw",
  "height": "100vh",  
  "backgroundColor": "blue"
}
```

I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Francisco, thank you so much! I tought that you can use both - frame + image. I replaced image with frame and it works.